# Flattern json objects using JsonPath

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

Is it possible to extract result to the flatten json using JsonPath. i.e., parent data should be fetched along with the child data?

Sample input:

```
{
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "iPhone",
      "numbers": [
        {
          "phone": "12345"
        },
        {
          "phone": "12346"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "home",
      "numbers": [
        {
          "phone": "12347"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and the expected result should be

```
[
  {
    "type": "iPhone",
    "phone": "12345"
  },
  {
    "type": "iPhone",
    "phone": "12346"
  },
  {
    "type": "home",
    "phone": "12347"
  }
]
```

Comment: I wrote my custom implementation to achieve the above result.